# Keras tensorflow backend modifying loss

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function, loss

Ok,
I have a bit of problem to modify the keras loss with tensorflow backend.

If I use keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy as loss, it would work as normal sparse_categorical_crossentropy.

However if I copy that source exactly and and hand over the copied function to the loss, then the following error occurs.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-118-840fee9ad06b> in <module>()
      3 
      4                   epochs=10, continue_train=False, load_model_weight=False,
----> 5              batch_size=256 * 1, common_columns=columns, code_columns=code_columns)

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    136                             ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have shape ' +
    137                             str(shape) + ' but got array with shape ' +
--> 138                             str(data_shape))
    139     return data
    140 

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_279 to have shape (37279,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

It seems like the original changes its value to one hot vectors, but the copied one does not. I can't find where it is changing the values.

In order to modify the loss, the original copy should work on my platform. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that keras introduces special output/target shapes checks if you use the `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` loss, as else you would get the same error as the targets are integers but the output is a vector. You can see the modification of the shapes used for checking [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/30fe4ff1f12ff0c45bac8738b4d2690eadd056b2/keras/engine/training.py#L772).

I don't know how to get rid of such error, the check only works if you use the `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`, and it seems to be no way to override the check for use with other losses. You might want to open a issue in the [keras github repo](https://github.com/keras-team/keras) asking for this feature.

Comment: Hello, I checked a several more things. If I hand over keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy then it would work while it would not if I use keras.backend.tensorflow_backend.sparse_categorical_crossentropy. Perhaps those two things are different?

Comment: I finally just managed to end up with replacing keras.losses.sparse_category_crossentropy with my own function on the instance. keras.losses.sparse_category_crossentropy = my_function. Then this would work as I intended